# Is this a valid method to find exactly $n$ consecutive composite numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Method**

Define a $n \times n$ prime matrix

\begin{equation*}
P_{n,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
p_{1,1} & p_{1,2} & \cdots & p_{1,n} \\
p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} & \cdots & p_{2,n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
p_{n,1} & p_{n,2} & \cdots & p_{n,n} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The corresponding pairwise coprime linear congruences to solve are

$x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p_{1,1} \cdots p_{1,n}}$
$\cdots$
$x+n \equiv 0 \pmod{p_{n,1} \cdots p_{n,n}}$

By the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), it has a unique solution $x$ for $\bmod{p_{1,1} \cdots p_{1,n} \times \cdots \times p_{n,1} \cdots p_{n,n}}$.

**Example**

To generate $3$ consecutive composites, define a prime matrix

\begin{equation*}
P_{3,3} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  3 &   5 \\
7 & 11 & 13 \\
17 & 19 & 23
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

The congruences to solve are

$x+1 \equiv 0 \bmod 30$
$x+2 \equiv 0 \bmod 1001$
$x+3 \equiv 0 \bmod 7429$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem,  the unique solution from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Reduce%5B%7BMod%5Bx%20%2B%201%2C%2030%5D%20%3D%3D%20Mod%5B0%2C%2030%5D%2C%20Mod%5Bx%20%2B%202%2C%201001%5D%20%3D%3D%20Mod%5B0%2C%201001%5D%2CMod%5Bx%20%2B%203%2C%207429%5D%20%3D%3D%20Mod%5B0%2C%207429%5D%7D%2C%20%7Bx%7D%2C%20Integers%5D) is

$x =  119740619 \pmod{223092870}$

so the $3$ consecutive composites are

```
119740620
119740621
119740622
```

**Notes**

There are simpler methods to generate $n$ consecutive composites

$(n+1)!+2 , (n+1)!+3 , ... , (n+1)!+(n+1)$

and the [Primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)

$n\#+2,n\#+3,…n\#+n$

**Question**

Is this a valid method and how can it be proved?

Comment: I see no reason to have more than a single column in that matrix, yielding$$x+1\equiv_20\\x+2\equiv_70\\x+3\equiv_{17}0$$Not that it is _wrong_. It just makes the answer a bit larger than it has to be.

Comment: Also note that @Arthur 's way of doing this makes it easier to create more solutions because the resulting mod would be smaller. Consider the following : $x + 1 \equiv_2 0$, $x + 2 \equiv_7 0$, $x + 3 \equiv_17 0$. From here, we get our general solution (of course, using CRT) as $x \equiv 201 \pmod 578$. This gives us much smaller solutions, as Arthur mentioned and getting more solutions would be easier.

Comment: @Hersh You really ought to use curly brackets in your MathJax. Slash commands are stingy with their arguments, so if you're not careful it only takes a single digit when you meant to give it more.

Comment: The catch of the "exactly" $n$ consecutive composite numbers is that the block must be surrounded by two prime numbers. Or do you just want to get a large block of many small consecutive composite numbers ?

Comment: @Arthur goodness gracious sorry I didn't realise I had made such a huge mess lmao. I was in a bit of a hurry and sleepy. I'll make sure to use curly brackets next time.

Comment: @Arthur Is this a valid method because what if I choose these $x+1\equiv_{7}0\\x+2\equiv_{11}0\\x+3\equiv_{23}0$ which gives $x=20$ by CRT, but $x+3=23$ isn't composite? Is there a way that the matrix primes must be chosen/setup?

Comment: @vengy The only thing that can go wrong is that $x$ is not only divisible by the prescribed prime, but _equal to it_. If that happens, then choose the nextsolution from the CRT instead. In this case, $x = 20 + 7\cdot11\cdot 23 = 1791$. Your matrix approach does indeed avoid this problem by making each modulus itself composite.