# Find a prime before or after some $n$ consecutive composite numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

**Goal**

I'd like a method to find a prime before or after some $n$ consecutive composites.

One method would be to brute force every prime and check for $n$ consecutive composites before or after it. Another is to check the prime gaps and keep searching until a gap  $\ge n$ is found.

**Method**

For primes $p_{1}<\cdots<p_{n}$, define these congruences

$$x+1\equiv_{p_{1}}0\\\cdots\\x+n\equiv_{p_{n}}0$$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT), the solution $x$ is

$x_k = ({p_{1} \cdots p_{n}})k+N$

yielding $n$ [consecutive composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4522959/is-this-a-valid-method-to-find-exactly-n-consecutive-composite-numbers)

${x+1,\cdots,x+n}$

Then $x+0$ or $x+n+1$ is prime for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Example**

Let primes $p_{1}=3, p_{2}=17$, then by CRT

$x = 51k+32$

When $k=1$, then $x=83$ is prime and occurs before these consecutive composites

$84,85$

**Question**

Is there a way to show the solution

$x_k = ({p_{1} \cdots p_{n}})k+N$

will always find a prime $x_k$ before or after $n$ consecutive composites?

**Answer**

As noted in the comments

> The arithmetic progression of solutions $x_k = (p_1\cdots p_n) k + N,\, k=1,2,\ldots$ contains
> infinitely many primes by Dirichlet, since $(p_i,N) = 1$ by $(p_i,x_k)=1.$

This shows there are infinitely many starting primes $x_k$ followed by $n$ composites, *infinitely often*.

Comment: Well, the standard trick is that $n! + 2$ through $n! + n$ will be $n-2$ consecutive composite numbers (because $n! + k$ is divisible by $k$).  Find the next or previous primes.  Of course *how* you find those primes is another issue.

Comment: The arithmetic progression of solutions $x_k = (p_1\cdots p_n) k + N,\, k=1,2,\ldots$ contains infinitely many primes by Dirichlet, since $(p_i,N) = 1$ by $(p_i,x_k)=1.\,$ Are you asking more than that? (your "goal" asks about an "efficient" method but your "question" asks only about existence, not an efficient algorithm).

Comment: There is no way to find a (new) prime more efficiently than sieving out small factors followed by a probable prime test.

Comment: @fleablood: $n! + 2$ through $n!+n$ gives $n-1$ consecutive composites.